# A Map of string, set. Comparing the value

Tags: c++, dictionary, set

I have a `map<string, set<string>>` and I have one entry, which is  `flights["Madison"].insert("Boston");`

Now I'd like to know how I can check if there is an entry in the map that is `"Madison", "Boston"`. I cannot think of a way to find if the value of the key in the set exists.

Here is my attempt thus far: I feel as though I'm a line or two away.

```
   typedef map<string, set<string>> TFlights;
   TFlights flights;
   TFlights::iterator iter, iter2;
   bool found = false;


   flights["Madison"].insert("Boston");
   flights["Madison"].insert("Miami");

   for(iter = flights.begin(); iter != flights.end(); iter++)
   {
      if(iter->first == "Madison" && //iter->second contains "Boston" )
      {
          found = true;
      }
   }

   return found;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `map::iterator` and the `find()` function for maps.  Once the value is found in the map, the `set` is searched:

```
bool found = false;
TFlights::iterator it = flights.find("Madison");
if ( it != flights.end())
{
   // key exists in map.  Now search the set
   if (it->second.find("Boston") != it->second.end())
     found = true;
}
return found;
```

Comment: So your line  iter->second.find("Boston") != iter->second.end() is going through the set to see if the value of "Boston" or whatever I'm looking for is in the set that way?

Comment: Yes.  That is how you search in a set.  Use the `find` method.  Both maps and sets have logarithmic search times (i.e. if you have a 1000 items to search, you only need 10 comparisons).  However you will defeat the purpose of this optimization if you write a for loop for the search (as your original post was doing).

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the description and example. This is my first footstep into the STL of c++. It worked perfectly. I took the logarithmic approach that you suggested and changed my code to be loop-free. [Apart from the find()]

Answer (score 0):

Replace your comment with 
`iter-> second.find("Boston") != iter-> second.end()`

Answer (score -2):

```
map<string, set<string>>::iterator i;
bool found = (i = flights.find("Madison")) != flights.end()) && i->count("Boston");
```

Comment: Pure code answers, without even a tiny, one-line explanation nearly always lands in VLQ queue and are eventually deleted. A user with nearly 50k rep should be aware of that.

Comment: @trejder: oh, what a relief!... for a moment there I thought I was doomed to overtax SO readers' fragile minds for all eternity.... ;-)